# Changing values in variables conditionally in R

Tags: r, database, if-statement, conditional-statements, character

```
    Romance     Horror Comedy  Keyword    
       0          1      1       lol         
       1          0      0       love         
       0          0      1       lol          
       1          1      0       omg
```

Hello everyone, I have a dataset like above and I'll work with R. What I want is like that:

If keyword="lol", make Comedy=1, others=0

If keyword= "omg", make Horror=1, others=0

If keyword= "love", make Romance=1, others=0

Actually, I've tried a ifelse statement but it didn't work. By the way, I want to mention that I have around 200 cases and 6 variables. Thanks for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is dummy or one-hot coding, so you can use `model.matrix` with a factor (or character) vector and a formula with no intercept:

```
~ x + 0
~ x - 1
```

either would work.

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Romance     Horror Comedy  Keyword
0          1      1       lol
1          0      0       love
0          0      1       lol
1          1      0       omg")

key <- c(Romance = 'love', Horror = 'omg', Comedy = 'lol')

tmp <- factor(dat$Keyword, key, names(key))

data.frame(model.matrix(~ tmp + 0))
#   tmpRomance tmpHorror tmpComedy
# 1          0         0         1
# 2          1         0         0
# 3          0         0         1
# 4          0         1         0
```

Since `key` (and therefore the levels of the factor) has the same order as your columns, you can also replace the columns directly:

```
dat[, 1:3] <- model.matrix(~ tmp + 0)
dat
#   Romance Horror Comedy Keyword
# 1       0      0      1     lol
# 2       1      0      0    love
# 3       0      0      1     lol
# 4       0      1      0     omg
```

---

edit

To map multiple words to a single genre, you can use a list for your key:

```
keywords <- c('lol', 'freak', 'kiss', 'ring', 'unknown', 'omg')

key <- list(
  Romance = c('love', "kiss", "ring"),
  Horror = c('omg', "freak", "kill"),
  Comedy = 'lol'
)

lst <- stack(key)
tmp <- lst$ind[match(keywords, lst$values)]

data.frame(model.matrix(~ tmp + 0))
#   tmpRomance tmpHorror tmpComedy
# 1          0         0         1
# 2          0         1         0
# 3          1         0         0
# 4          1         0         0
# 6          0         1         0
```

Note that the above did not match the keyword that was missing from the list (row 5 is missing), so it would be useful to have a separate category for these, too:

```
key <- c(key, Other = setdiff(keywords, unlist(key)))

lst <- stack(key)
tmp <- lst$ind[match(keywords, lst$values)]

data.frame(model.matrix(~ tmp + 0), keywords)
#   tmpRomance tmpHorror tmpComedy tmpOther keywords
# 1          0         0         1        0      lol
# 2          0         1         0        0    freak
# 3          1         0         0        0     kiss
# 4          1         0         0        0     ring
# 5          0         0         0        1  unknown
# 6          0         1         0        0      omg
```

And now row 5 shows up correctly

---

edit2

I just learned that R >= 3.5.0 *finally* allows duplicated labels, so instead of doing

```
key <- c(key, Other = setdiff(keywords, unlist(key)))
lst <- stack(key)
lst$ind[match(keywords, lst$values)]
# [1] Comedy  Horror  Romance Romance Other   Horror 
# Levels: Romance Horror Comedy Other
```

you can simply do

```
factor(keywords, unlist(key), rep(names(key), lengths(key)))
# [1] Comedy  Horror  Romance Romance Other   Horror 
# Levels: Romance Horror Comedy Other
```

Comment: But I want to ask something more, what if I want to add more keywords for each type like key <- c(Romance = c('love', "kiss", "ring", Horror = c('omg', "freak", "kill"), Comedy = 'lol') when I create vector for each type and then try tmp <- factor(data$kodlar, key, names(key)) code, it worked but then there were 3 different romance columns like tmpRomance1, tmpRomance2, tmpRomance3. I can create another variable by combining these 3 columns. Is there any other way or is this ok?

Comment: @IlaydaVelioglu you would need to use a `list` in that case and map multiple words to a single factor level, see the edits

Answer (score 2):

Change the column values to 1 for the first three columns

```
df1[1:3] <- 0
```

Then, create a named vector to match with the column names

```
nm1 <- setNames(c("Comedy", "Romance", "Horror"), c("lol", "love", "omg"))
```

Use the vector to `match` the column names of 'df1' based on the replaced values from 'Keyword' to get the column index, `cbind` with the row index, use that matrix of row/column index to assign those elements from dataset to 1

```
df1[1:3][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), match(nm1[df1$Keyword], names(df1)))] <- 1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Romance = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Horror = c(1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L), Comedy = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Keyword = c("lol", "love", 
"lol", "omg")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```